# ¿ Cómo averiguar la palabra más corta y contar sus caracteres?

Tags: javascript, array, string

Cómo creo una función que saque la palabra más corta y me cuente las letras que tenga. He buscado sin éxito, lo único, descubrí la forma de encontrar la palabra más larga.
Yo quería la más corta y contar los caracteres, que eso imagino se haría metiendolos en un array.
Si me dan alguna idea de como hacerlo.
Gracias.

```js
function buscaCorta(s) {
            palabraCorta = ""
            palabras = s.replace(",", " ").split(" ");
            palabras.forEach(function (palabra) {
                if (palabra.length > palabraCorta.length) {
                    palabraCorta = palabra
                };
            });
            return palabraCorta
        };

        alert(buscaCorta("Quiera la palabra mas corta y ver sus caracteres"));
```

Comment: A ver si me aclaro. ¿Tienes el código para encontrar la palabra más larga... y no sabes como encontrar la palabra más corta? ¿Sabes como funciona tu código?

Comment: No se cambiarlo para sacar la mas corta, solo es eso

Comment: Como palabra corta es una cadena vacía inicialmente, su longitud siempre va a ser menor o igual que la palabra más corta de la lista.

Comment: Ya le he pillado, solo me queda contar los caracteres de esta, en cuanto lo consiga edito o pongo una respuesta si no lo hace nadie. Gracias @AlvaroMontoro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solo debes cambiar el signo `>` por `<` y en la variable `palabraCorta` poner un texto exageradamente grande, para esto se pone la palabra que se le pasa por parametro en la función

```js
function buscaCorta(s) {
    palabraCorta = s;
    palabras = s.replace(",", " ").split(" ");
    palabras.forEach(function (palabra) {
        if (palabra.length < palabraCorta.length) {
            palabraCorta = palabra
        };
    });
    return palabraCorta
};

alert(buscaCorta("Quiera la palabra mas corta y ver sus caracteres"));
```

Comment: Gracias @Samir Llorente, lo saque tambien eliminando la parte `if (palabra.length < palabraCorta.length)`  Solo me queda que me diga tambien el numero de caracteres, para cual tendre que crear otra funcion

Comment: Para el tamaño no es necesario la funcion simplemente asigna tu funcion a un variable `hola=buscaCorta("Quiera l...")` y luego simplemente llama a `lenght` de tu variable `hola.lenght` esto te dara el tamaño del String